# MySql : Can I use query results in nested queries as a variable?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to save server resources and reduce number of queries

what I need is to use a variable holding a query result in another query as a nested query like this

```
$names = ("SELECT * FROM table WHERE username like 'M%'");
```

This will return all names starting with `M` in `table`

later I want to use `$names` as a nested query like this

```
 $myname = ("SELECT * FROM $names WHERE username='Mohammad'");
```

I saw an answer that suggests to create a temp table from first query result in memory but this is not what I need, because I'll keep `$names` for a long time and I can't keep the table in the memory all time, this will drawn server resources.

I tried it like the syntax above and with many ways similar to it but it didn't work

I don't want to do it in 1 query like this because this will execute nested query every time I need to use `$names`

```
 $myname = ("SELECT * FROM ("SELECT * FROM table WHERE username like 'M%'") WHERE username='Mohammad'");
```

because I need first result as a separate variable to use it in other places of my script.

**Edit**

I need the first query because I'll do many queries based on it like

```
 $name = ("SELECT * FROM $names WHERE username='Many'");
 $name = ("SELECT * FROM $names WHERE username='Mando'");
```

and so on

Comment: why don't you just `select * from table where username = 'Mohammad'`?

Comment: Doing `SELECT * FROM $names` and if someone searches for a non-existant table such as "Manhattan" from your previous search, your query will fail. You will need to use conditional statements.

Comment: I edited my question. thank you all

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the double quotes and make your first table as a new table let say `tbl1':

```
$myname = ("SELECT * FROM 
                        (SELECT * FROM table WHERE username like 'M%') as tbl1 
           WHERE tbl1.username='Mohammad'");
```

I think you just need to adjust the query become:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE username = 'Mohammad';
```

> In this case, no need to nest the table since you use the same table.

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the list of all names like this:

```
$names = $database->query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE username like 'M%'");
```

Then loop through the names you retrieved and handle each one at a time:

```
$count = $names->rowCount();
for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
    if($names[$i]['username'] == "Mohammed") {
        // do something
    }
}
```